# Delete an item from a list on the basis of a condition

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

below is the code of my class. The code creates an ArrayList.  It then adds a number of  “PipesList” to the ArrayList, adding Pipes within each list.

I want to write a method -RemoveTheSmallPipes to get rid of all of the pipes with lengths less than 19. For which, I have written a piece of code which I don't know works or not! as the code throws an error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0050: Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less accessible than method 'Program.RemoveTheSmallPipes(System.Collections.Generic.List)'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>




   public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<PipesList> lstPipeTypes = new List<PipesList>();

        lstPipeTypes.Add(new PipesList("PVC Pipes"));
        lstPipeTypes[0].Pipes.Add(new Pipe("The blue pipe", 12));
        lstPipeTypes[0].Pipes.Add(new Pipe("The red pipe", 15));
        lstPipeTypes[0].Pipes.Add(new Pipe("The silver pipe", 6));
        lstPipeTypes[0].Pipes.Add(new Pipe("The green pipe", 52));

        lstPipeTypes.Add(new PipesList("Iron Pipes"));
        lstPipeTypes[1].Pipes.Add(new Pipe("The gold pipe", 9));
        lstPipeTypes[1].Pipes.Add(new Pipe("The orange pipe", 115));
        lstPipeTypes[1].Pipes.Add(new Pipe("The pink pipe", 1));

        lstPipeTypes.Add(new PipesList("Chrome Pipes"));
        lstPipeTypes[2].Pipes.Add(new Pipe("The grey pipe", 12));
        lstPipeTypes[2].Pipes.Add(new Pipe("The black pipe", 15));
        lstPipeTypes[2].Pipes.Add(new Pipe("The white pipe", 19));
        lstPipeTypes[2].Pipes.Add(new Pipe("The brown pipe", 60));
        lstPipeTypes[2].Pipes.Add(new Pipe("The peach pipe", 16));


        lstPipeTypes = RemoveTheSmallPipes(lstPipeTypes);

        foreach (var pipeList in lstPipeTypes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PipesList: {0}", pipeList.pipeType);

            foreach (var pipe in pipeList.Pipes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, length: {1}", pipe.name, pipe.length);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done, press return to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public static List<PipesList> RemoveTheSmallPipes(List<PipesList> lstPipeTypes)
    {

        //Place your code in here
        //It should remove all pipes that have lengths lower than 19.


        foreach (var pipeList in lstPipeTypes)
        {

            foreach (var pipe in pipeList.Pipes)
            {

                    lstPipeTypes.RemoveAll(i => pipe.length < 19);

            }

        }

        return lstPipeTypes;

    }
}

class PipesList
{
    public string pipeType;
    public List<Pipe> Pipes;

    public PipesList(string newBoxType)
    {
        pipeType = newBoxType;
        Pipes = new List<Pipe>();
    }
}

class Pipe
{
    public string name;
    public float length;

    public Pipe(string newName, float newLength)
    {
        this.name = newName;
        this.length = newLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is part of the preliminary test that my company (Xibis, www.xibis.com, we advertise on the right >>) issues to developer candidates before they come and sit a more complicated test in house, to ensure that they have a grounding in basic development skills so we don't waste our time, or the candidates time. To any candidates thinking of using the answers below: we are aware of these answers, so if you submit them as your own you will not be invited for the in house test. Please attempt to answer the questions on your own.

Comment: I was not able to get the answer. I have asked this here so that I can know how to solve errors like this and can keep in mind for future if I face similar errors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is part of my companies preliminary test that we give candidates before we invite them for an in house test.

Comment: @IanNewson why do you think it is off-topic? Is it just because it's in your test? This question is about programming, doesn't fail any point discussed in the the help page where off-topic scope is defined and the intention to ask this here is to learn and not to qualify your exam. I first discussed it with my senior and then posted here as I still had doubt in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `PipesList` class is `internal`, so it's only visible to other code within the same assembly. Your `RemoveTheSmallPipes` method is *public*, but refers to `PipesList` in its signature. That's not allowed.

Either make `RemoveTheSmallPipes` method internal, or make `PipesList` public.

Your implementation is also somewhat odd, by the way. It's unclear why you've got two levels of loops *and* a `RemoveAll` call, but the fact that you don't use your lambda expression parameter (`i`) within the body of the lambda expression is very suspicious. It's not clear what you're trying to do, but I don't think your code does what you expect at the moment...

EDIT: Based on your description, I suspect the body should look like this:

```
foreach (var pipeList in lstPipeTypes)
{
    pipeList.Pipes.RemoveAll(pipe => pipe.length < 19);
}
```

Comment: @Tigran: Shouldn't what be private by default?

Comment: I was trying to access the list using loop and then by using lambda expression with a condition that if the length of the pipe is less than 19, the pipe item should get removed from the list.

Comment: @SidP: See my edit. Currently you're calling `RemoveAll` on a list of PipeLists, not on a list of pipes...

Comment: Your code to remove the pipes works! Thanks! But, one of my other senior member has said that we don't have to modify the public and internal identifiers. Is there any other way we can remove the error I was getting?

Comment: @SidP: Your other senior member was wrong :) You simply can't have a public method in a public class referring to an internal type within its parameters or return type.

Comment: Ok..I will report this concept to him. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Pipe and PipesList classes aren't public, yet are being returned by a public method.

Answer (score 0):

Class PipesList is internal (by default) but RemoveTheSmallPipes() is public.

Either make class PipesList public, or RemoveTheSmallPipes() internal.

Answer (score 0):

1. The compiler shows the following error:
   "Inconsistent accessibility: return type `System.Collections.Generic.List` is less accessible than method `Program.RemoveTheSmallPipes(System.Collections.Generic.List)`"
   This refers to the visibility of the respective types: Your return type `List<PipesList>` is *internal* (because the generic argument `PipesList` is *internal*), but your method is *public* (i.e. more visible than *internal*). Make your method *internal*, then this compiler error message should disappear.
2. Your `RemoveTheSmallPipes` method is probably going to throw an exception; you should not change collections while iterating over them.